# Share Converter Result

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to share the result of the converters,  to prevent the execution of each converter for each binding

something like this:

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Resource>
    <Visibility x:Key="VisibilityResource" >
        <Binding Path="myEnum" Converter="EnumToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Visibility>
  </UserControl.Resource>

    <StackPanel   VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="Button1" Height="80" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"  />
        <Button Content="Button2" Height="80" Visibility="{StaticResource VisibilityResource} />
        <Button Content="Button3" Height="80" Visibility="{StaticResource VisibilityResource} />
        <Button x:Name="Button4" Content="Button4" Height="80" Visibility="{StaticResource VisibilityResource} />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

for example, an alternative solution is:

```
<StackPanel   VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Content="Button1" Height="80" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"  />
    <Button Content="Button2" Height="80" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Button4 , Path=Visibility}"/>
    <Button Content="Button3" Height="80" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Button4 , Path=Visibility}"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button4" Content="Button4" Height="80" Visibility="{Binding myEnum, Converter={StaticResource EnumToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: You could add a static dictionary to your converter and base the key on the type and value. But I don't really get why you need such a thing. A converter is meant to be lightweight. You should think about your structure first, before going that ways.

Comment: This method helps me to debug the program more easily, It also prevents additional execution, for example, the string to image converter is not light when using in too many elements.

Comment: Can you explain your suggestion more?

Comment: Your example of the `string` to `image` converter is good example of bad approach. You should have somewhere a cache for your images. The converter just gives the cache the key and the cache returns the image. The converter is lightweight as you see, because the loading and caching is done on the image cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the class (there are many similar implementations on the Internet):

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

In resources, declare an instance of this class and need the binding in the Data property:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy  x:Key="VisibilityResource" 
                         Data="{Binding Path, Converter={StaticResource EnumToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Further in XAML you can set the binding to its Data property:

```
<StackPanel   VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Content="Button1" Height="80" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"  />
    <Button Content="Button2" Height="80" Visibility="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource VisibilityResource}}" />
    <Button Content="Button3" Height="80" Visibility="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource VisibilityResource}}" />
    <Button x:Name="Button4" Content="Button4" Height="80" Visibility="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource VisibilityResource}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is not through Resources, but using the Tag property of any element and a binding of the ElementName type:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stPnl"   VerticalAlignment="Center" Tag="{Binding Path, Converter={StaticResource EnumToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <Button Content="Button1" Height="80" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"  />
    <Button Content="Button2" Height="80" Visibility="{Binding Tag, ElementName=stPnl}" />
    <Button Content="Button3" Height="80" Visibility="{Binding Tag, ElementName=stPnl}" />
    <Button x:Name="Button4" Content="Button4" Height="80" Visibility="{Binding Tag, ElementName=stPnl}" />
</StackPanel>
```

There are many more solutions.
If you are not satisfied with the above, then write in more detail what you need.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of this Question I want to share my research with others:
The best solution is to use BindingResourceExtension and the BindingProxy from [EldHasp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13349759/eldhasp) :

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(bool))]
[Localizability(LocalizationCategory.NeverLocalize)]
public class BindingResourceExtension : StaticResourceExtension
{
    public BindingResourceExtension() : base() { }
    public BindingResourceExtension(object resourceKey) : base(resourceKey) { }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return base.ProvideValue(serviceProvider) is BindingBase binding
            ? binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider)
            : null;
    }
}


public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy));
        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() => new BindingProxy();
        public object Data
        {
            get => (object)GetValue(DataProperty);
            set => SetValue(DataProperty, value);
        }
}
```

and in the XAML we have:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <windows:BindingProxy  x:Key="VisibilityResource" 
                             Data="{Binding myEnum, Converter={StaticResource EnumToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        <Binding Path="Data" Source="{StaticResource VisibilityResource}" x:Key="MyBinding" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel   VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <Button Content="Button1" Height="80" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"  />
      <Button Content="Button2" Height="80" Visibility="{windows:BindingResource MyBinding}"/>
      <Button Content="Button3" Height="80" Visibility="{windows:BindingResource MyBinding}"/>
      <Button Content="Button4" Height="80" Visibility="{windows:BindingResource MyBinding}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The advantage of this method is that it is easier to debug, and also the converter runs once. as you can see, the duplicate code is also reduced.